# How to fix "'@IBInspectable' attribute is meaningless on a property that cannot be represented in Objective-C" warning

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9-beta

In Xcode 9 and Swift 4 I always get this warning for some `IBInspectable` properties:

```
    @IBDesignable public class CircularIndicator: UIView {
        // this has a warning
        @IBInspectable var backgroundIndicatorLineWidth: CGFloat? {  // <-- warning here
            didSet {
                backgroundIndicator.lineWidth = backgroundIndicatorLineWidth!
            }
        }

    // this doesn't have a warning
    @IBInspectable var topIndicatorFillColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            topIndicator.fillColor = topIndicatorFillColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Maybe.

The exact *error* (not *warning*) I got when doing a copy/paste of class `CircularIndicator: UIView` is:

> Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be
> represented in Objective-C

I resolved it by making this change:

```
@IBInspectable var backgroundIndicatorLineWidth: CGFloat? {  // <-- warning here
    didSet {
        backgroundIndicator.lineWidth = backgroundIndicatorLineWidth!
    }
}
```

To:

```
@IBInspectable var backgroundIndicatorLineWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        backgroundIndicator.lineWidth = backgroundIndicatorLineWidth
    }
}
```

Of course, `backgroundIndicator` is undefined in my project.

But if you are coding against `didSet`, it looks like you just need to define a default value instead of making `backgroundIndicatorLineWidth` optional.

Comment: I still get the warning, even after I remove the optional and add default value.

Comment: Then there has to be something (besides a closing bracket) different between the code you posted and your project code. My *error* (which may be an indication) disappeared. I'll edit my answer with that code.

Comment: it's ok now, they are gone. I guess it took some time for Xcode to update

Comment: Almost added the edit. Guess that's overwork. Glad I could help.

Comment: And what if I still need the optional property? :-)

Comment: I'd probably *try very hard* to not make an optional IB property (since `IBDesignable` is meant for *visible* properties, shouldn't they have a default?), but maybe try defaulting to `nil`? I'm not stating that such a thing would work, but it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 9):

Below two points might helps you

1. As there is no concept of optional in objective c, So optional IBInspectable produces this error. I removed the optional and provided a default value.
2. If you are using some enumerations types, then write @objc before that enum to remove this error.

Comment: > As there is no concept of optional in objective c
it is not exactly true. Classes is ObjC are nullable by design. UIColor is a class. So, correct equivalent of ObjC's `UIColor` in Swift is `UIColor?`

Answer (score 5):

Swift - 5

```
//Change this with below
@IBInspectable public var shadowPathRect: CGRect!{
    didSet {
        if shadowPathRect != oldValue {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

To

```
@IBInspectable public var shadowPathRect: CGRect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0) {
    didSet {
        if shadowPathRect != oldValue {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```