# @IBInspectable: Property cannot be marked

Tags: swift, ibinspectable

## I keep getting this error:

> Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be
>   represented in Objective-C

.. why does its type need to be represented in Ojective-C? And is there a simple way to solve this problem?

#### This is the code snippet where the error occurs:

```
@IBInspectable open weak var dataSource: ColorMatchTabsViewControllerDataSource? {
    didSet {
        _view.scrollMenu.dataSource = dataSource == nil ? nil : self
        _view.tabs.dataSource = dataSource == nil ? nil : self
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `@nonobjc` declaration before the var definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "'@IBInspectable' attribute is meaningless on a property that cannot be represented in Objective-C" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024160/how-to-fix-ibinspectable-attribute-is-meaningless-on-a-property-that-cannot)