# Segue from Obj-c to swift can't find property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue, objc-bridging-header

i'm attempting to passing an `int` from objective-c file to swift.

The steps that I have taken do indeed segue, however sadly it does not pass the int across due to the following error: `Property 'productKey' not found on object of type 'ProductViewController *'`

**Prepare Segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewProduct"]) {
    ProductViewController *destVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    destVC.productKey = brandID;
  }
}
```

**Perform Segue**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewProduct" sender:self];
});
```

**Swift File**

```
class ProductViewController: UIViewController {

    var productKey: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           print(productKey)
    }
}
```

**Header Bridge**

```
 //
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "ARSceneViewController.h"
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `@objc` in front of either `var productKey` or `class ProductViewController`?

Comment: @dfd Hey, adding the '@objc' in front of the var in the swift file did, in fact, mute the objective c error. However, I'm now not sure how to create the var empty for the segue to set.

Comment: @dfd I get the following error: 'property cannot be marked objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C'

Comment: My most upvoted answer may help you - basically add a default value. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024160/how-to-fix-ibinspectable-attribute-is-meaningless-on-a-property-that-cannot/46024414#46024414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Swift file in objc classes Bridging header won't help here.

Xcode will create Header file which you need to import

First goto build settings and search for **Defines Modules** and set it to true.

Now in `.m` file add following header file

```
#import "YourTargetName-Swift.h"
```

and build the project

and also add `@objc` before your property

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Hey, adding the @objc in front of the var in the swift file did, in fact, mute the objective c error. However, I'm now not sure how to create the var empty for the segue to set.

Comment: I get the following error: 'property cannot be marked objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C'

Comment: @MattHammond Could you please try **@objc**  before the class name and also try to replace int with NSNumber

Comment: When I change it to NSNumber it then makes me change the value type in objective-c file. This mutes the errors but when segueing it passing none to swift. Errorr - Assigning to 'NSNumber * _Null_unspecified' from incompatible type 'int'